# Loading a ViewController based on rotation in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rotation

I am trying to do something I feel is very easy, however, I can't seem to get it.  I have two View Controllers.  Depending on the rotation of the iPhone, I want to show one of the controllers.  I have been able to determine if the phone is rotated by putting some code in the appDelegate but I can't seem to load a View Controller based on the rotation.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you have done in your AppDelegate or how your app is structured as far as navigation, tab bar, or other flow structures, I'll provide a way that is actually found in the [Apple Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html) and can be manipulated in several way to fit your needs:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Request to turn on accelerometer and begin receiving accelerometer events
    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    // Add an observer to this class that will trigger a method when it receives an "orientation did change" notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

We first request that this class (which ever view controller you would expect to naturally be displayed first) ask the device to start generating orientation notification. Next, we add an observer to this class to allow us to accept these notification and fire the next method when it does.

```
override func orientationChanged(notification: NSNotification) {

    // create appropriate view controller for new orientation
    let newViewController = customViewControllerClass() // or maybe a storyboard view controller Identifier

    // present new view controller
    self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        // maybe some code here to handle this view while we can still access it easily
        // we also don't have to have this presentation be animated
    }
```

Here we created our method that will run when the observer receives the notification. In it, we create the new view controller that we want and then simply display it.

While this could be also be implemented in the second view controller, it may be wise to instead think about some sort of control structure like a navigation controller that can manage your views for you. With one, you could easily push/pop view controller instances to the navigation stack. While the above method is easy and works, it is technically, and possibly endlessly, creating views and presenting them on top of each other, whereas a navigation based implementation would really only have two views being pushed and popped off the nav stack, thus saving system resources.

Also, using a control structure to conditionally load your views from gives you the opportunity to first query the system for the current orientation, and keep doing so rather than have the individual views both do it. Just don't forget to implement the last method outlined in the Apple Developer Library link above that removes the observer and stops generating device orientation notifications.